# typescript interface with array union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

Seems that this flags array for union type does not really work for me.
I have been playing with idea that implementing class must provide flags about interfaces it's implementing which is also easy to get out from implementing class.
Flags as `flags: Record<T & FeatureFlagType, true>` works, but this also doable with array context?
I have tried with all different combinations for flags like (T & FeatureFlag)[] but nothing seem to work.

```js
type FeatureFlagType = 'feature1' | 'feature2';

interface FeatureFlag<T extends FeatureFlagType> {
    flags: T[];
    flagsRecords: Record<T, true>;
}

interface Feature1 extends FeatureFlag<'feature1'> {
    doFeature1: () => void;
}

interface Feature2 extends FeatureFlag<'feature2'> {
    doFeature2: () => void;
}

class Instance implements Feature1, Feature2 {
    public flags = ['feature1' as 'feature1', 'feature2' as 'feature2']; // not ok
    public flagsRecords = {feature1: true as true, feature2: true as true}; // this is ok
    public doFeature1() {

    }
    public doFeature2() {

    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYhCGwCuAnCMA28DmAVc0AvFAOQBmCyaAjCVAD6kWKoQBMJA3AFDcCWAO2AQUZeAGNocFmkw4APLigQAHsIEATAM6xKrOXgIA+KAG9uUS1DJZsWgFxQlAMl0z0t-JADaAXR4AvryCwqISUno0ymoQmjrSVB4K5JEQtCbmVlAaAPYJrNSOABQAlFCEJgBuOXwagcFCImKSbols0erarfq28inuHBkWVrn5aGzFZRVQ1bX13OJYWjoAkgJawPACLXwAtmAYELuxwPGp1AA03eNmw5ZgSABGGHzi1rY6xN79ibRQ8DofgUSFcgeM6ACmKkOP47lAHs9Xtk8udSrc4UEsgiXm9RtC0eYMdwAkA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`implements` enforces an intersection of types. And the problem here is that:

```
'a'[] & 'b'[] // never
```

So this will not work. What you want is a union of strings for the `flags` array, but `implements` will not do that for you.

However an intersection will work with records:

```
Record<'a', string> & Record<'b', string> // { a: string, b: string }
```

---

Here's an alternative approach:

```
// See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type FeatureFlagType = 'feature1' | 'feature2';

interface FeatureFlag<T extends FeatureFlagType> {
    flag: T;
}

type HasFeatures<T extends FeatureFlag<FeatureFlagType>[]> =
    { flags: T[number]['flag'][] }
    & UnionToIntersection<Omit<T[number], 'flag'>>


// intended usage:
class A implements HasFeatures<[Feature1, Feature2]> {
  //...
}
```

Now each feature has a single flag. The `HasFeatures` accepts an array of features, and makes an array of all possible features as the `flags` property.

Then all non `flag` properties and intersected together and merged with the type, so the types gets all feature interfaces.

(In order to get the intersection of the array of feature interfaces, some [voodoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) is required)

But now this works as you would expect:

```
interface Feature1 extends FeatureFlag<'feature1'> {
    doFeature1: () => void;
}

interface Feature2 extends FeatureFlag<'feature2'> {
    doFeature2: () => void;
}

class Instance implements HasFeatures<[Feature1, Feature2]> {
    public flags = [
        'feature1' as const,
        'feature2' as const
    ];
    public doFeature1() {

    }
    public doFeature2() {

    }
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUFNILlALALogDgZxiNiCGBjAawHsA3SAJwDMAbIgdwDo8iBbYARwFdJsBLIgHZpgAVgAMAZgDsAFgCcYgBzBE5HEMpFyLALScB-ATsQBPFJGNEdvAYgppIeRIeNnIAKFPnQAVQOCAFSIASVt7R2dBAB4fAD5QAF5Qd1BQAAofUEgADzsBABM0UHUTUAB+dII4HwBKBNiSIl580DgBSDJyGqzcyAKitLSq0BtKClBguoam-O6K4NbQds73Vc83UAAxSBxETnJITeocAHMAjaSAcjHd-cgARkvQAB9Qa529g4AmS4BuVZsdio+EgWw+dyOpyiAR6eUKYNuB0hZzc8QA3ilUqAaKc4AF-gBfVZeUEACRwaG2iJ40NhfXhVM+h2OJyijIhLPO5liAG0ALrxBKY1Jo7EsjCgAI8gScFgAIwofJ51xZlyVfNARKxoAAZL5-AIgqEgQ4nIYogB5Fi8RDQ6WyhXkPkAGjeOJOl1isTWgIolBBCKZ9zp-UDHKh72pj3RwtA+SI7IO9zgaW69VAjWahIBYWBeFBicgXxDDPBSJZUUjTJ+Me18cLXxTafimfy2fceGOaCKoWw6nzIxYKGokBYfUQRXJlLLNJ5hfurobAtAGO1KE4cuovDwYtORSSPNj2qrd0exSKzCEiGdR6xJ++TwpoEv2FjfP+a43W539Zn91TK6rNqWpYuum7bnGCYzl8AEYrGRIEkAA)

Comment: I do like HasFeatures way

Comment: seems that it only requires first flag value to be valid?

Comment: If you want to make a feature that has no properties, you could I guess. I don't think it's worth guarding against that.